# getMessage not returning mocked value

Tags: mocking, mockito

I'm not getting a mocked value from Mockito getMessage.
Not sure what I am doing wrong. Any ideas?

Test case :

```
SQSJSONMessage sqsJSONMessage = mock(SQSJSONMessage.class);

when(objMapper.readValue(message,SQSJSONMessage.class)).thenReturn(sqsJSONMessage);

doNothing().when(listener).decryptAndReplaceMessage(sqsJSONMessage);

when(objMapper.readValue(sqsJSONMessage.getMessage(), RecordCreatedMessage.class)).thenReturn(recordCreatedmessage);

when(sqsJSONMessage.getMessage()).thenReturn("test");   -- this throws null pointer exception
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing I noticed is that you are using `sqsJSONMessage.getMessage()` in the 2nd stub of objMapper, also you probably should move the stub of `sqsJSONMessage.getMessage()` before that:

```
when(sqsJSONMessage.getMessage()).thenReturn("test");
when(objMapper.readValue("test", RecordCreatedMessage.class)).thenReturn(recordCreatedmessage);
```

Use `anyString()` instead of `"test"` if you don't care about the parameter.